# Pass select/drop-down item's value to controller only receives 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I've successfully created a view to show some records from votings. But on that same view i try to call another method on my controller to export those records and it only receives 0 as a parameter.

This is my model.

```
public class Vote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CPF { get; set; }
        public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
        public int CandidateID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Moment { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Index.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var context = _context.Vote.Include(v => v.Candidate).Include(v => v.Candidate.Election);
            //This is going to be on the view for the user to select the year to export data
            ViewData["Election"] = new SelectList(_context.Election, "Id", "Year");
            return View(await context.ToListAsync());
        }
```

That's the action I'm tryig to call.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Export(int electionYear)
```

This is the form I'm using to POST to the controller.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Vote>
...
//Here i show the votes and then below i show this form with the Elections
<form asp-action="Export">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Election"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Exportar" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried it with the [FormBody] and it gives me 415 ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Export` endpoint is expecting a form value called `electionYear`.  But your `<select>` doesn't have that `name` (or any `name`).  Try:

```
<select name="electionYear" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Election"></select>
```